# List<String> get count of all elements ending with one of strings from another list

Tags: java, java-stream, partitioning

Let's say I have one list with elements like:

```
List<String> endings= Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD");
```

And I have another large list of strings from which I would want to select all elements ending with any of the strings from the above list.

```
List<String> fullList= Arrays.asList("111.AAA", "222.AAA", "111.BBB", "222.BBB", "111.CCC", "222.CCC", "111.DDD", "222.DDD");
```

Ideally I would want a way to partition the second list so that it contains four groups, each group containing only those elements ending with one of the strings from first list. So in the above case the results would be 4 groups of 2 elements each.

I found this example but I am still missing the part where I can filter by all endings which are contained in a different list.

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> grouped = fullList.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy((String e) -> !e.endsWith("AAA")));
```

UPDATE: MC Emperor's Answer does work, but it crashes on lists containing millions of strings, so doesn't work that well in practice.

Comment: Do your "endings" always have the same length?

Comment: "*crashes on lists containing milions of strings*" is not helpful. What do you mean by *crashes*? You get an out of memory error? Your IDE literally crashes and closes itself? Your program hangs? Your program computes the result for a long time and you think it froze?

Comment: @Fureeish crashes Netbeans

Comment: Then it's Netbeans' fault, not the code's. Or maybe fault of your adaptation. I suggest changing your IDE or best, testing your code with raw `.java` files compiled and run via console (just for this example).

Comment: Inefficient code cannot break your IDE, unless the IDE is itself broken. It can result in slow computation, but not in something like an IDE crashing. *Efficiency* has nothing to do with this case, unless you provided incorrect information.

Comment: @Fureeish memory-inefficient, not CPU. It would do you no harm to read up before replying with such certainty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200015/discussion-between-delica-and-fureeish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `fullList` have some elements which have suffixes that are not present in your `endings` you could try something like:

```
    List<String> endings= Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD");
    List<String> fullList= Arrays.asList("111.AAA", "222.AAA", "111.BBB", "222.BBB", "111.CCC", "222.CCC", "111.DDD", "222.DDD", "111.EEE");
    Function<String,String> suffix = s -> endings.stream()
                                                 .filter(e -> s.endsWith(e))
                                                 .findFirst().orElse("UnknownSuffix");
    Map<String,List<String>> grouped = fullList.stream()
                                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(suffix));
    System.out.println(grouped);
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

This one is similar to the approach from the original answer, but now `fullList` is no longer traversed many times. Instead, it is traversed once, and for each element, the list of endings is searched for a match. This is mapped to an `Entry(ending, fullListItem)`, and then grouped by the list item. While grouping, the value elements are unwrapped to a `List`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> obj = fullList.stream()
    .map(item -> endings.stream()
        .filter(item::endsWith)
        .findAny()
        .map(ending -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ending, item))
        .orElse(null))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

---

#### Original answer

You could use this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> obj = endings.stream()
    .map(ending -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ending, fullList.stream()
        .filter(str -> str.endsWith(ending))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

It takes all endings and traverses the `fullList` for elements ending with the value.

Note that with this approach, for each element it traverses the full list. This is rather inefficient, and I think you are better off using another way to map the elements. For instance, if you know something about the structure of the elements in `fullList`, then you can group it immediately.

Comment: @delica that doesn't follow the specification you gave under my answer : *I mean the resulting map should have an entry for elements with this ending but it should be empty, or size 0.*

Comment: Yes, this indeed crashes Netbeans when run on a very long list. So it doesn't actually work that well on the real data I have.

Comment: @delica I have added another approach, which, I think, performs better.

Comment: The updated version still does a linear search through `endings` [which can be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117645/2711488). Of course, if `endings` stays small, that’s not a concern. If the search function doesn’t use `null` as a fall-back, the function can be used directly as the grouping function, making dealing with `Map.Entry` unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

To partition a stream, means putting each element into one of two groups. Since you have more suffixes, you want *grouping* instead, i.e. use `groupingBy` instead of `partitioningBy`.

If you want to support an arbitrary `endings` list, you might prefer something better than a linear search.

One approach is using a sorted collection, using a suffix-based comparator.

The comparator can be implemented like

```
Comparator<String> backwards = (s1, s2) -> {
    for(int p1 = s1.length(), p2 = s2.length(); p1 > 0 && p2 > 0;) {
        int c = Integer.compare(s1.charAt(--p1), s2.charAt(--p2));
        if(c != 0) return c;
    }
    return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
};
```

The logic is similar to the natural order of string, with the only difference that it runs from the end to the beginning. In other words, it’s equivalent to `Comparator.comparing(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())`, but more efficient.

Then, given an input like

```
List<String> endings= Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD");
List<String> fullList= Arrays.asList("111.AAA", "222.AAA",
        "111.BBB", "222.BBB", "111.CCC", "222.CCC", "111.DDD", "222.DDD");
```

you can perform the task as

```
// prepare collection with faster lookup
TreeSet<String> suffixes = new TreeSet<>(backwards);
suffixes.addAll(endings);

// use it for grouping
Map<String, List<String>> map = fullList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(suffixes::floor));
```

But if you are only interested in the count of each group, you should count right while grouping, avoiding to store lists of elements:

```
Map<String, Long> map = fullList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(suffixes::floor, Collectors.counting()));
```

If the list can contain strings which match no suffix of the list, you have to replace `suffixes::floor` with `s -> { String g = suffixes.floor(s); return g!=null && s.endsWith(g)? g: "_None"; }` or a similar function.

Answer (score 3):

Use [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = fullList
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\.")[1]));
```

`s.split("\\.")[1]` will take the *yyy* part of *xxx.yyy*.

EDIT : if you want to empty the values for which the ending is not in the list, you can filter them out:

```
grouped.keySet().forEach(key->{
  if(!endings.contains(key)){
    grouped.put(key, Collections.emptyList());
  }
});
```

Comment: Where are you using the endings list?

Comment: Do you need the ending list? What should you do if the ending is not contained in that list?

Comment: Yes, I need sub-groups by each ending. Then it should be empty.

Comment: What do you mean by empty? It should not be included in your result?

Comment: I mean the resulting map should have an entry for elements with this ending but it should be empty, or size 0.

Comment: Your code still does not use the endings list to group by.

Comment: @delica because I don't need the endings list to group by?
I group by the suffixes and then empty the ones for which the suffix is not contained in the list. That respects your specifications.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a helper method `getSuffix()` that accepts a `String` and returns its suffix (for example `getSuffix("111.AAA")` will return `"AAA"`), you can filter the `String`s having suffix contained in the other list and then group them:

```
Map<String,List<String>> grouped =
    fullList.stream()
            .filter(s -> endings.contains(getSuffix(s)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> getSuffix(s)));
```

For example, if the `suffix` always begins at index 4, you can have:

```
public static String getSuffix(String s) {
    return s.substring(4);
}
```

and the above `Stream` pipeline will return the `Map`:

```
{AAA=[111.AAA, 222.AAA], CCC=[111.CCC, 222.CCC], BBB=[111.BBB, 222.BBB], DDD=[111.DDD, 222.DDD]}
```

P.S. note that the `filter` step would be more efficient if you change the `endings` `List` to a `HashSet`.

Comment: @delica so you just have to change the `getSuffix()` method. It was only an example.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `groupingBy` of substrings with `filter` to ensure that the final `Map` has just the `Collection` of relevant values. This could be sone as :

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = fullList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> getSuffix(a)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> endings.contains(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

private static String getSuffix(String a) {
    return a.split(".")[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupingBy` with filter on `endings` list as,

```
fullList.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(str -> endings.stream().filter(ele -> str.endsWith(ele)).findFirst().get()))
```